# Comparing dissimilarity measures using PCA in R

Tags: r, pca, vegan

I would like to compare the behaviour of several dissimilarity measures (i.e. Bray-Curtis, Jaccard, Gower). I have seen this done using a principal component biplot (i.e. see Legendre and Caceres, 2013 below):

[image]

Any suggestions how one goes about this? Sample data provided below:

```
# Load the required packages
library(ade4)
library(vegan)
library(FD)

#Load data
data(dune)

# Calculate a series of dissimilarity measures for the data
dune.bc <- vegdist(dune, method="bray")
dune.mh <- vegdist(dune, method="manhattan")
dune.eu <- vegdist(dune, method="euclidean")
dune.cn <- vegdist(dune, method="canberra")
dune.k <- vegdist(dune, method="kulczynski")
dune.j <- vegdist(dune, method="jaccard")
dune.g <- vegdist(dune, method="gower")
dune.m <- vegdist(dune, method="morisita")
dune.h <- vegdist(dune, method="horn")
dune.mf <- vegdist(dune, method="mountford")
dune.r <- vegdist(dune, method="raup")
dune.bi <- vegdist(dune, method="binomial")
dune.c <- vegdist(dune, method="chao")

#Compare the behaviour of the dissimilarity measures using a PCA plot
# Suggestions on how proceed with this step would be greatly appreciated!
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, that's not what the authors do. If you *read* that paper, the PCA biplot is one of the matrix of properties of each dissimilarity coefficient, *not* a PCA of on *k* dissimilarity matrices. Basically, they analysed Table 2 in the paper via PCA (minus the column at the far right, labelled *D*max).

I don't know a way to compare dissimilarity matrices, other than via a Procrustes rotation and associated PROTEST permutation test, or a Mantel test, perhaps: see `procrustes()`, `protest()` and `mantel()`

You can look at the `rankindex()` of the coefficients with the gradient values as another comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I am aware that the PCA is based on a 1-0 matrix of dissimilarity properties, I  was just using their graphic as an example of what I would like to in terms of illustrating different behaviour of dissimilarity measures.

I will explore your suggestions and post an answer if they lead to a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Elizabeth Then think about how they structure their data, each column in the input data is variable that describes a property of the dissimilarity coefficient. You have computed several dissimilarity matrices and thus just have data relating to pair-wise dissimilarity. The authors have 1 matrix of data, you have *n* dissimilarity matrices. Those two aren't ever going to mesh. What are your criteria for judging or comparing dissimilarity coefficients? It seems you are interested in which maps your data *best*? And that is quite different to what the paper you cite does.

Comment: I take your point. What I ultimately am trying to show is the similarity of similarity indices in terms of the results they produce (clustering, PCA or whatever) for a given data set. I would like some way of showing this graphically. Of course I could show a series of clustering or PCA results, one for each similarity measure but what I am looking for is a way to directly compare the differences in the results they produce.

Comment: @Elizabeth Then checkout `procrustes()`, for comparing the ordinations produced from the respective dissimilarities.

Comment: Thank you. I will do so.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is a Second Stage Analysis?

Take several dissimilarity matrices, generate pairwise rank correlations between all of them and this greats a dissimilarity matrices of your dissimilarity matrices. From there you can use NMDS to plot them all.  In general you'll find that similar calculations (i.e. eucleadian family, bray-curtis family, ect.) group closely within.

Check out:
Exploring interactions by second-stage community analyses. (2006) clarke, somerfield, airoldi, and warwick

Here they do what you suggest, or want:
On resemblance measures for ecological studies, including taxonomic dissimilarities and a zer-adjusted Bray-Curtis coefficient for denuded assemblages. (2006) Clarke, Somerfield, and Chapman.